# why no visiablity var in multi-thread can always get one result in my macbook pro;

Tags: java, multithreading

why no visiablity var in multi-thread can always get one result in my        macbook pro;

```
public class NoVisiability  {
    private int count = 1;
    private boolean ready = false;

    public void read() {
        if (ready) {
            count = count * 3;
        }
        System.out.printf("the count is %s", count);
    }

    public void write() {
        count = 2;
        ready = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NoVisiability noVisiability = new NoVisiability();
        noVisiability.new ReaderThread(true).start();
        noVisiability.new ReaderThread(false).start();
    }

    private class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        private boolean flag;

        public ReaderThread(boolean flag) {
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (flag)
                write();
            else
                read();
        }
    }
}
```

share variable can be reorder;
so the result can be 6,0,3;
but i run it many times, the result always is 6

Comment: Your question is pretty difficult to understand. Please provide more information concerning the code you shared, like what it does, what the expected output is and what the actual out is.

Comment: Chances are your write thread is completely finishing before the read thread even starts. It probably also runs on the same processor.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the JVM in Mac decides to execute all in the same thread. It is also likely that the first thread finishes before the second one is started.

To force a bit the concurrency I'd suggest using this class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

You can create one with count=1, await in the first line of "public void run" and trigger it after both threads have been created and started.